# Calculate the joint probability distribution of $x$ and $y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$\phi$ is a random phase angle that is distribute uniformly over the range 0 to $2\pi$, $a$ is  a constant, and $x=a\cos(\phi)$, $y=a\sin(\phi)$.

I have a doubt on how to find the joint probability distribution. I don't know if there is a formal definition that tells me how to find it.

I understand that the joint probability distribution function is denoted by a function $f(x,y)$ but I don't know how to obtain it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Extreme case, since $x^2+y^2=a^2$ constant.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Excuse my ignorance, what do you mean by "extreme case"?

Comment: x and y are completely locked.  In general, dependence is partial.  Note: this question was asked recently by PCat27.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263827/how-to-compute-the-probability-distributions-and-the-joint-probability-distribut